# boolean return value in mathematica

Tags: boolean-computation

why does the following instruction ok in mathematica, and it returns a boolean value

```
In[398]:= catenary[x, 1, 0, 0] == catenary[-x, 1, 0, 0]
Out[398]:= True
```

and not this one?

```
In[406]:= catenary[-x, 1, 0, 0] == -catenary[x, 1, 0, 0]
Out[406]:= Cosh[x] == -Cosh[x]
```

I wanted to have a boolean value too.. to prove the symmetry..
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wrap the entire thing in `TrueQ[]` if need be. Less facetiously: your last equation is true for `x` an odd multiple of $\dfrac{\pi i}{2}$ and false otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use three "="s, i.e.,

```
Cosh[x]===Cosh[-x]
```

(* True *)

If you need the Boolean value, then

```
Cosh[x] === Cosh[-x] // Boole
```

(* 1 *)

Comment: `Cosh[x] == Cosh[-x]` works fine; *Mathematica* is not too dumb to not know that the hyperbolic cosine is even.

Comment: @J.M. But Sinh[x]==Sinh[-x] return itself, which is not the purpose of the programmer, whereas, Sinh[x]===Sinh[-x] works fine.

Comment: Again: `Sinh[]` is not the function in the OP.

Comment: This is an example to illustrate the way to cope with the problem. I don't think the author  need Cosh ONLY but no other functions.

Comment: You'd think that, until you see OP's other questions...

Comment: OK, you're right. But === is a robust way, I insist.